# Error 'not found' when declaring variables correctly

Tags: bash

I have a file called "s1" and it contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=5
var2=4
if (( var1 > var2 ))
 then 
  echo "$var1 more than $var2"
fi
```

On executing the file I get the following:

```
s1: 4: var1: not found
```

In most cases, such an error occurs due to incorrect declaration of variables, for example:

```
var1 = 5
```

but I'm declaring the variable without any extra spaces.
While executing this script, I noticed that I have created two files with the names `4` and `var2` respectively
Why am I getting such an error?

Comment: Your script works as expected on my linux. No idea what you have done! You simply set exec bits and call it?

Comment: Yes. I execute the file with `sh s1` command. By the way, when I write the script in a line in the terminal it works: `var1=5; var2=4; if (( var1 > var2 )); then echo "$var1 > $var2"; fi`

Comment: Why you answer with "yes"? You did something totally different! You run a bash script with `sh` shell which simply can't work. So you should simply set exec bit and execute the file itself instead of calling a shell manually. We should close the question as the problem has nothing to do with the code shown or the text provided in the question. Please vote to close!

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Now I run the script with `./s1` command and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the script with [`sh`, not `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/4518341). For example you might be doing `sh s1`. You should be doing `./s1` so that the system will use the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to determine which interpreter to run the script with.

I'm not sure how `sh` interprets double-parens `(( ))`, but it's certainly not the same as Bash, so it's trying to run a command called `var1` and redirect the output to a file called `var2`.

As for why you have a file called `4`, you probably tried adding a dollar sign `$` at some point.